# Answer-stealing user with bad attitude

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, plagiarism

This is about *[position 2 divs next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169169/position-2-divs-next-to-each-other/33169480?noredirect=1#comment54146625_33169480)*.

There's this guy who downvotes every single answer on this question, then looked at my comment containing a jsFiddle. He then decided it was perfectly fine to copy it into his own answer.

When I said something about it, he quickly deleted the answer and made a new one with slightly different classes. Then downvoted my original answer.

Can there be something done about this kind of attitude? I'm sure he didn't get all of those reputation points on his own... I already flagged him.

He's now downvoting all of my existing answers...

[image]

Comment: His (serial) downvoting will be detected by the script tonight, and reversed. Don't worry about that.

Comment: 60 rep? There are only 5 downvotes, for a total of 10. Anyway, wait 24h before asking for help, there's a vote-anomaly script.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I flagged my own answer linking to this post with an explanation and flagged his answer too.

Comment: Lesson learned: don't post a JSFiddle in a comment; make it an answer right away.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Exactly. I was trying to be constructive and finding out if this was something the OP was looking for, before making the actual comment explaining it, but it seems that's just not possible.

Comment: You really shouldn't call out people on Meta. Flag for a Moderator and let them handle it.

Comment: *"who downvotes every single answer on this question, then looked at my comment containing a jsfiddle. He then decided it was perfectly fine to copy it into his own answer."* I see absolutely nothing wrong with that. Your comment is not an answer, and he felt it was an answer so he posted it. It would have been nice of him to provide attribution though.

Comment: Regarding your [most recent edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/308184/4), if you're concerned that this user left no evidence behind, then you're actually mistaken, because deleted answers can still be viewed by users with at least 10k rep, and deleted comments are viewable my elected moderators (people with ♦ next to their names). You can't just destroy records of your activities on Stack Overflow so easily. Almost *everything* we do is recorded here, in some form or another.

Comment: I see, good to know! Edited my edit accordingly ;) Thanks a lot, my SO knowledge is a hell of a lot higher because of this post

Comment: Unrelated: I really hope @Pekka웃 runs for moderator in the next election. He'd do well.

Comment: it's just sad that people feel they have to act this way to get ahead :/

Comment: Am I the only one that noticed that the question that received all this attention, not to mention 10 answers, is most likely a duplicate?

Comment: After reading your comments on the answer, I feel like you egged the situation on. You should always [assume good intentions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). In the future, you might ask the person if they would give you attribution in the answer. Saying things like "Did you seriously just...wow..Thanks for taking my rep...I actually feel very sorry for you now" is antagonistic.

Comment: Did you ask him why he did it?

Comment: @KevinB You're right that he was okay to copy it into his answer, but under the site content license he was actually _required_ to give attribution.  I think.

Comment: @apaul34208: I don't know, but clearly you're the only one who thought it relevant enough to point out. What was the discussion about again?

Comment: FYI, the user has actually been suspended for an entire year now. I actually caught him possibly committing voting fraud on the answer in question by possibly having a sock puppet account voting up his answer immediately after he undeleted it. He's also requested that his account be deleted too though, so I doubt we'll be seeing much of him in the near future. Oh yeah, I also found that 15 of his answers were plagiarized from other sources, and I haven't even finished looking through them all yet.

Comment: @Bob: "I doubt we'll be seeing much of him in the near future" Famous last words...

Comment: @BoltClock Ya... it may be a tangent, but still...

Comment: This user had been at this a while... it was not picked up by the system. Depressing. :( http://stackoverflow.com/a/28545808/1240268

Comment: @Andy Hayden: There are no system checks for plagiarism. Not saying that isn't depressing, but yeah.

Comment: @BoltClock it's the plagarism + downvotes + users deleting the earlier/plagarised answers (presumably due to that downvoting)... incredibly depressing. Edit: take it back, these look like they were deleted *before*... strange.

Comment: This is not the first time this user displays questionable behavior. Last time, he posted a question with a sock puppet, then an [answer that looks good at first glance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896329/regex-to-match-egyptian-hieroglyphics/28918460#28918460), but contains completely wrong regex for most of the languages.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Raise a moderator flag on any of your answers, explaining the behaviour and linking to this post. They'll deal with it appropriately.

Comment: Another example of fraud by moderator himself and that's for just 2 points - https://twitter.com/angrycomments/status/764472121535832067

Answer (score 18):

Im flagging this and his answer in this thread for Moderator Attention.

In any case, there is a script preventing serial downvoting that will reverse it by tomorrow.

Now him admitting in plain text that he directly and intentionally violated a SO site rule, however...

Edit: He changed his name to something offensive and deleted all the relevant posts... Maturity through and through I see...

Comment: Thanks! And I was not aware of this script (and actually thought he was doing more harm than just 10 rep. Anyway, his whole attitude just doesn't belong here and I'm 100% sure that 1800 rep was made this way.

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld I dont know about that. Maybe he isn't a serial plagiarist. But this instance is enough for moderator attention and some cool-off time, imo.

Comment: I don't know about that either. The very first thing I do when seeing users acting inappropriately  on SO  (or whining about getting suspended or something) is check out their profiles for plagiarism. At a very quick glance, it seems that for all his abrasive behaviour, this user's other answers look ok

Comment: @MohitBhasi - It's not about the "amount" but about the Quality.

Comment: It looks like you did in this case though, @Mohit

Comment: You took code directly from where he posted a jfiddle, and then changed it only ever so slightly when called out on it, all while trying to hide evidence. If thats not plagiarism with malicious intent, I don't know what is.

Comment: @MohitBhasi I couldn't care less about the rep at this point, it's just your attitude. If you removed your answer and said "Oops sorry" when I called you out on it, it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Some people around here happen to be pretty good at catching plagiarism... *<evil laugh>* ...

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'll be sure to add "whining, poorly-behaved" users to my plagiarism detection algorithms... `>:D`

Comment: @Mohit, you say you don't plagiarize, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480648/464709) of yours indicates the opposite. Sure, you're clever enough to rip content from both [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/464709) and [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36911/464709), but the result is still pretty transparent.

Comment: @MohitBhasi Let's try to remember the "be nice" rule? please.... (and other people on this comment thread as well I guess)

Comment: @MohitBhasi This is in no way helpful to the community. When you get treated "not nicely", you flag, you move away, and then you behave nicely. If you didn't like being treated "not nicely" and retaliate in kind, how will ANYTHING improve? You rise above it and you become the better person.

Comment: @MohitBhasi depends on what you feel is "not nice". Sometimes new users flag a lot of "not nice" stuff that is just someone being curt and suggesting ways to improve a post. I don't have specifics on your case so I can't pronounce myself, but I've seen my share of new users coming to meta with "HE WAS RUDE TO ME" when the comment was "you'll get a better reception here by showing more research efforts"

Comment: @MohitBhasi (and that is not mentioning that EVEN THEN, I don't consider that kind of "he was mean to me, so that excuses me being mean" kind of attitude. We're not in kindergarten to keep that kind of petty mentality.)

Comment: Just because other people break the rules does not give you the right to. Additionally, I've had an account here for two weeks, and I have had very few unpleasant examples of the community here. In fact you are the first very unpleasant person i've encountered on here yet.

Comment: @Magisch I guess you won't encounter him anymore. Either he got suspended, or he deleted EVERYTHING he put on meta (and the answer that was linked here) and changed his username...

Comment: @Patrice He changed his username and deleted a few dozen posts. See the user link in the OP. Actually, the link is even gone from the Op. Here is his new user name: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4417613/user4417613

Comment: @Magisch  yeah I realized the link still existed after posting my comment. In any case, normally that kind of "cut n run" attitude means you will not see him again

Comment: @Magisch: That's not what he changed it to. That's what *I* changed it to ;) What *he* changed it to, was far more amusing (for certain definitions of "amusing").

Comment: @BoltClock Ahh so you were that, I just thought he changed it again to throw people off scent. Does SO have permaban features for people who have this little interest in contributing?

Comment: @Magisch users are usually given temporary suspensions for this sort of thing. Users are rarely perma-banned, though I suppose that it happens once every blue moon.

Comment: Frysian hardship. Come-up, be a man. Do something really complicated e.g. on [Scala.JS Fiddle](http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com) Get away from the VMBO crowd.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ha, good find!

Comment: @Pekka웃 never mind, I'm just going to grab the answer IDs out of SEDE and clear them out later.

Comment: @Bob great! i'm not in the position to be of much help right now.

Comment: "This account is temporarily suspended"... for one year. I approve.